# Can you override a computed property in a struct nested type / extension nested type?

Tags: swift, oop, inheritance

Suppose there is some struct, with a nested struct that has some functionality I want to modify or extend. How do you override a computed property of a struct, when the computed property is inside a nested struct? Example:

```
public struct Foo {
  var c: Int
  init(c: Int) {
    self.c = c
  }
  // Suppose there's lots of implementation
}

extension Foo {
  struct FooContent {
    var a: Int
    public var b: Int { self.a + 1 }

    init(a: Int) {
      self.a = a
    }
  }
  // Suppose there's lots of implementation
}

var obj = Foo.FooContent(a: 1)
print(obj.b)
```

Suppose I want to override `b` to be `self.a + 2`, and not touch any other functionality in `Foo` or `FooContent`. Is there a way to do this something along the lines of

```
extension Foo.FooContent {
    public var b: Int { self.a + 2 }
    // won't compile because b is already defined
}
```

Seems like a big hole in the language design that structs + extension functionality can't be inherited. I figure I'm missing something.

Comment: A Swift struct can't be subclassed (substructed?). Extensions add new functionality, they can't be used to change existing functionality.

Comment: It's not a design hole, it's pretty intentional, actually. Apply the ["What if two ~programs~ extensions did this?"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413) principle. Suppose this were possible, and you could use an extension to override a method on a struct. What would happen to callers who relied on the original behaviour of the struct? Or what if two extensions tried to provide two different override for the same method on the same struct?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your usecase, and what you're trying to achieve (and less about _how_ you've tried to achieve it, so far)? What's the relationship between `Foo` and `FooContent`

Comment: @Alexander I added a bit of explanation. There is a library I want to modify that follows this design pattern (there is a struct + nested struct in an extension), and I want to modify a computed property in the nested struct while keeping most of the functionality inside the struct and nested struct exactly the same.

Comment: Well you can't do that.

Comment: @Murd you haven’t really answered my question. You’re giving me detail on how you would envision you’d solve your problem, but you haven’t explained the actual problem itself. For example, perhaps your problem can be solved without needing 2 strut and thus completely bypass this issue altogether.